# Intel Performance Primitive library for OpenCV- not finding some functions in the library class

Tags: opencv, intel-ipp

I was using lately IPP with my openCV code .. and it worked perfectly "Thanks GOD"..

I used it to do sharpening on my image and now I want to use it to implement function for color recognition .. so I wanted to use this function which I locate in the documentation of the library -->

ippiBlurInitAlloc

that was the error message I got -->

```
ERROR: ‘ippiBlurInitAlloc’ was not declared in this scope
```

the problem is that the library cannot be found .. and when I went to the header file where the function is suppose to be "ippcv.h" I didn't find the function. So I went online and decide to search for the function and when I did .. I found another implementation of the header file which contains the function on that [website](http://www.hackchina.com/en/r/198208/ippcv.h__html)

so I downloaded it and replace it with the current version of ippcv.h and recompile the installation of OpenCV but it gave me this error -->

```
  ../core/include/opencv2/core/internal.hpp:99,
             from/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/precomp.hpp:57,
             from /OpenCV-2.3.1/build/modules/imgproc/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/ipp/include/ippcv.h:2462:2: error: expected   unqualified-id before ‘...’ token
make[2]: *** [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.dir  /opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
```